# Use php time() instead of now() in MySQL/PHP-script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL-query sent from PHP to MySQL, which f.e. looks like this:

```
SELECT (now()-table.created) FROM table
```

Now I need to replace the MySQL-function "now()" with a a date from PHP (because it's not always "now" I want in the query), but it doesn't work when I pass PHPs "time()" to MySQL.

What PHP method could I use?

Comment: I think I just found it: $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); - correct?

Comment: Use [`DateTime`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a function called [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime),

```
-- NOW() => time()
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
-- time() => DATETIME()
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1366223878)
```

Comment: I hate from deep of my heart append PHP into a MySQL query.

Comment: ok, I understand your approach and although I had to think more about your solution it seems to be the best... thanks!

Comment: Won't this still inflict time-inconsistancies? I'm stumped. If the time gets fetched at that same point (as said in the OP) it's still inaccurate.

Comment: can't I use the time()-function in PHP and pass it inside "FROM_UNIXTIME" - I know @WesleySchleumer will "hate it from deep of his heart" but wouldn't that be correct?

Comment: yep, seems to work, f.e. FROM_UNIXTIME(1366224926) gives me the actual time (a few minutes ago :)) and the value 1366224926 is taken from php, exactly what I need.

Comment: You can do that too, i understand your needs, @Allendar is right, time will still inconsistent, but you can do something like `sprintf("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)", time());`

Comment: it's not that the time-difference in milliseconds or even seconds is really that relevant. Performance however is! I suppose MySQL will only calculate that "FROM_UNIXTIME(1366224926)" once per query if the value doesn't change?

Comment: If value doesnt change, it's calculated once per query.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, well, it depends on the format that `table.created` is stored in.

If it's a UNIXTIME value (i.e. the same format as PHP's time), then all you need to do is interpolate it in the right way:

```
<?php
$dbobj->query('SELECT ('.time().'-table.created) FROM table');
?>
```

... if, instead, `table.created` is a datetime or similar value, you'll need to create the appropriate date format:

```
<?php
$dbobj->query("SELECT ('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())."'-table.created) FROM table");
?>
```

Comment: thanks! Actually it's "timestamp", so I'll use "date('Y-m-d H:i:s');", correct?

Comment: Yep, for your purposes here "timestamp" and "datetime" would be handled in the same way.

Comment: It's strongly recommended to use the newer class-approaches in PHP.

Comment: `date()` doesn't appear to be deprecated or recommended against on the documentation page.  You may get a lot more from the newer class approaches, but for a simple case like this where you're taking an explicit epoch time and converting it into an explicit format, `date()` should be perfectly acceptable.  That said, learning newer, more robust methods never hurt anyone, so I can't recommend against your suggestion.

Comment: You are correct. The new class also re-uses the old approaches. It's just nice, clean and a lot easier to manipulate the time with DateTime, as you will always access the methods inside the object and directly manipulate that time. Also it's a big plus you can easily add/subtract and see differences between different date-objects. Last but not least, timezone and offset operations are way easier with DateTime. Enough reasons to let the old functions go :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer DateTine object;

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW');

$query = "SELECT * FROM table where date > ".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

The `NOW` in the DateTime object will be accurate to your liking, as it's stored on the moment you seem to want it, unlike when done in MySQL, which may be (micro/milli)seconds later.